# Extract text from first and last strings

Tags: bash, sed, string

I want to extract text from a string matching the first and last word

string is a path :

`/path/to/the/file/app.apk(randomcharacters)`

and I want to extract text like

`/path/to/the/file/app.apk`

using something like this

`sed '/\/path/.apk/'`

only sed command required as answer

Comment: Is the `(` character guaranteed to be the separator between the path and the random string? If so, use it to remove the _trailing_ stuff: `s/(.*//`. Note that `(` is a perfectly legitimate character in a filename, so you'd better be sure of your domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your paths follow the same pattern: `.apk(somerandomcharracters)` you can remove by replacing all after the pattern `.apk`. There are two ways of removing the unnecessary characters:

**Solution 1**

```
sed "s/\(\.apk\).*/\1/g" <<< '/path/to/the/file/app.apk(characters)'
```

The problem with the code above is that if some directory contains the pattern `.apk` or `.apk(randomchars)` the output will not be as you would expect, e.g.

```
sed "s/\(\.apk\).*/\1/g" <<< '/path/to/the/file.apk/app.apk(characters)'
#This will print:
/path/to/the/file.apk
```

**Solution 2**
If you want to avoid the problem above you will have to use:

```
sed "s/\(.*\.apk\).*/\1/g" <<< '/path/to/the.apk212/file.apk12ll/app.apk(aa)dfd'
#This will print:
/path/to/the.apk212/file.apk12ll/app.apk

sed  "s/\(.*\.apk\).*/\1/g" <<< '/path/to/the/file/app.apk(aa)dfd'
#This will print 
/path/to/the/file/app.apk
```

By the way, I would rather use roaima's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use POSIX string manipulation - no need for an external command such as `sed`.

```
s='/path/to/the/file/app.apk(randomcharacters)'
echo "${s%.apk*}.apk"
```

Output

```
/path/to/the/file/app.apk
```

This does necessarily presuppose that your "*random characters*" are not truly random and therefore do not include the string `.apk`. If they might contain this string but your path (prefix) can be guaranteed not to include it, then you can replace `%` with `%%`.